# Why does mathematica repeat my differential equation again?Does it mean no solution?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic

I am trying to solve this
\begin{equation}
(1-\frac{2}{r})\partial_r^2 u+\frac{2}{r}(1-\frac{1}{r})\partial_r u+\frac{1}{r^2} \partial^2_x u+\frac{\cot x}{r^2} \partial_x u-\frac{\cos x}{r^2}(1+\frac{2}{r}+\frac{18}{5r^2})=0
\end{equation}
The code is following:

```
DSolve[(1 - 2/r) D[u[r, x], {r, 2}] + (2/r)*(1 - 1/r)*
    D[u[r, x], {r, 1}] + (1/r^2)*D[u[r, x], {x, 2}] + (Cot[x]/r^2)*
    D[u[r, x], {x, 1}] - (Cos[x]/r^2)*(1 + 2/r + 18/(5*r^2)) == 0 , 
 u[r, x], {r, x}]
```

But mathematica just repeats my input(seebelow)
[image]
Does it mean no solution to the equation?

Comment: Please post the Mathematica code directly ,not the LaTeX or pictures.

Comment: As @cvgmt says, need to see the actual code but note that your Latex code shows u[r,x] as the coefficient of the Cot[x] term and the image of your Mathematica code shows D[u[r,x],{x,1}]

Comment: I have added my code..

Comment: I don't know if it matters, but your latex doesn't match your screenshot doesn't match your code for your `Cot` term.

Comment: @Bill yep,, I have fixed the cot term in my latex

Comment: Any reason you expect this highly complicated PDE to be solvable analytically? Most actually don't have have closed form solutions, but if you saw the solution in some paper or book, please add that info, it'd definitely help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mathematica V 13.1 currently can not solve this pde.

Here is the solution using another CAS system. But that solution is not fully complete since it depends on functions $F1(x),F2(r)$ as solutions that have to satisfy separate second order odes. But these ode's are solvable. Hence the complete solution can now be constructed.

Hopefully next version of Mathematica will be able to solve this pde.

```
restart; 
with(MmaTranslator);
pde:=FromMma(`(1-2/r) D[u[r,x],{r,2}]+(2/r)*(1-1/r)*D[u[r,x],{r,1}]+(1/r^2)*D[u[r,x],{x,2}]+(Cot[x]/r^2)*D[u[r,x],{x,1}]-(Cos[x]/r^2)*(1+2/r+18/(5*r^2))==0`);
```

[image]

Now

```
 sol:=pdsolve(pde,u(r,x))
```

Gives

$$
\begin{align*}
u \left(r , x\right)=F1 \left(r \right) F2 \left(x \right) - \frac{A}{B}
\end{align*}
$$

Where

$$
\begin{align*}
A&=\left(\frac{C1 \left(-8 \ln \left(-r +2\right) \ln \left(2\right) r^{2}+8 \ln \left(2\right)^{2} r^{2}+4 \ln \left(r \right)^{2} r^{2}+8 \ln \left(-r +2\right) \ln \left(2\right) r -8 \ln \left(2\right)^{2} r +8 \mathit{dilog}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right) r^{2}-29 \ln \left(r -2\right) r^{2}-4 \ln \left(r \right)^{2} r +29 \ln \left(r \right) r^{2}-8 \mathit{dilog}\left(\frac{r}{2}\right) r +29 \ln \left(r -2\right) r -45 \ln \left(r \right) r -69 r +18\right)}{r}+C2 \left(r -1\right)+C3 \left(-\frac{\ln \left(r \right) r}{2}+\frac{\ln \left(r \right)}{2}+\frac{\ln \left(r -2\right) r}{2}-\frac{\ln \left(r -2\right)}{2}+1\right)\right) \cot \left(x \right) \sin \left(x \right) \left(r^{2}+2 r +\frac{18}{5}\right)\\
B&=24 C1 \left(r^{2} \left(r -\frac{1}{3}\right) \ln \left(\frac{r}{2}\right)+r^{2} \left(r -\frac{1}{3}\right) \ln \left(2\right)+\left(-r^{3}+\frac{1}{3} r^{2}\right) \ln \left(r \right)+\frac{5 r^{2}}{12}+\frac{5 r}{6}+\frac{3}{2}\right)\\
\frac{d^{2}}{d r^{2}}F1 \left(r \right)&=\frac{F1 \left(r \right) c_{1}}{\left(r -2\right) r}-\frac{2 \left(\frac{d}{d r}F1 \left(r \right)\right) \left(r -1\right)}{\left(r -2\right) r}\\ 
\frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}}F2 \left(x \right)&=-\cot \left(x \right) \left(\frac{d}{d x}F2 \left(x \right)\right)-F2 \left(x \right) c_{1}
\end{align*}
$$

The Latex might be hard to read since it is long. Here is also screen shot

[image]

Here is also plain text code of the solution which the Latex represents: (This can also be translated to Mathematica from Maple, but I did not do that here)

```
u(r,x) = _F1(r)*_F2(x)-1/24*(_C1*(-8*ln(-r+2)*ln(2)*r^2+8*ln(2)^2*r
^2+4*ln(r)^2*r^2+8*ln(-r+2)*ln(2)*r-8*ln(2)^2*r+8*dilog(1/2*r)*r^2-29*ln(r-2)*r
^2-4*ln(r)^2*r+29*ln(r)*r^2-8*dilog(1/2*r)*r+29*ln(r-2)*r-45*ln(r)*r-69*r+18)/r
+_C2*(r-1)+_C3*(1/2*ln(r-2)*r-1/2*ln(r-2)+1-1/2*ln(r)*r+1/2*ln(r)))*sin(x)*cot(
x)*(r^2+2*r+18/5)/(r^2*(r-1/3)*ln(1/2*r)+r^2*(r-1/3)*ln(2)+(-r^3+1/3*r^2)*ln(r)
+5/12*r^2+5/6*r+3/2)/_C1
```

With $F1,F2$ are solutions of

```
diff(diff(_F1(r),r),r) = _F1(r)/r/(r-2)*_c[1]-2*diff(_F1(r),r)*(r-1)/r/(r-2)

diff(diff(_F2(x),x),x) = -_F2(x)*_c[1]-cot(x)*diff(_F2(x),x)
```

Note that Maple dilog function is defined as

[image]

So need to be careful if you want to translate the above solution to Mathematica.

The functions $F2(x)$ and $F1(r)$ can be solved by Mathematica, which now gives you the full solution:

```
DSolve[F2''[x] == -Cot[x]*F2'[x] - F2[x]*c[1], F2[x], x]
DSolve[F1''[r] == F1[r]*c[1]/((r - 2)*r) - 2*F1'[r]*(r - 1)/((r - 2)*r), F1[r], r]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks,, it looks crazy. I also see some $\log(2-r)$ terms, does it mean the solution is complex in the region $r>2$?

Comment: By the way, does mathematica provide any approximate solution in addition to NDSolve?

Comment: @Sven2009 as far as I know, `AsymptoticDSolveValue` does not work for pde's only odes'. So NDSolve will be your next choice (but you need full specification in this case to use NDSolve)

Comment: Nice solution (+1).  Interesting, Mathematica cannot handle even the corresponding homogeneous PDE, `DSolve[r^2 ((1 - 2/r) D[u[r, x], r, r] + (2/r)*(1 - 1/r)*D[u[r, x], r]) + D[u[r, x], x, x] + Cot[x]*D[u[r, x], x] == 0, u[r, x], {r, x}]`, even though it is separable.

Comment: Thanks.  Beautiful.   Pleasure to be in a group that does so much with DEs.

Answer (score 9):

Mathematica can, in fact, solve this PDE with some human assistance.  Because the PDE is linear, its solution is the general solution of the corresponding homogeneous PDE plus any specific solution of the inhomogeneous PDE.  The former can be obtained by separation of variables:

```
pdeh = (r^2 ((1 - 2/r) D[u[r, x], r, r] + (2/r)*(1 - 1/r)*D[u[r, x], r]) + 
    D[u[r, x], x, x] + Cot[x]*D[u[r, x], x]) /. u -> Function[{r, x}, ur[r] ux[x]];
Simplify[%/(ur[r] ux[x])]
(* (2 (-1 + r) ur'[r] + (-2 + r) r ur''[r])/ur[r] + 
   (Cot[x] ux'[x] + ux''[x])/ux[x] *)
```

General solutions for {ur[r], ux[x]} are

```
DSolveValue[pdeh[[1]] == -c, ur[r], r, GeneratedParameters -> Cr]
(* Cr[1] LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 c]), -1 + r] + 
   Cr[2] LegendreQ[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 c]), -1 + r] *)

DSolveValue[pdeh[[2]] == c, ux[x], x, GeneratedParameters -> Cx]
(* Cx[1] LegendreP[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 c]), Cos[x]] + 
   Cx[2] LegendreQ[1/2 (-1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 c]), Cos[x]] *)
```

where `c` is the separation constant. Given that the inhomogeneous term in the PDE is proportional to Cos[x], itself a `LegendreP`, a plausible guess for an inhomogeneous solution is `u0[r] Cos[x]`.

```
((1 - 2/r) D[u[r, x], {r, 2}] + (2/r)*(1 - 1/r)*
    D[u[r, x], {r, 1}] + (1/r^2)*D[u[r, x], {x, 2}] + (Cot[x]/r^2)*
    D[u[r, x], {x, 1}] - (Cos[x]/r^2)*(1 + 2/r + 18/(5*r^2))) /. 
    u -> Function[{r, x}, u0[r] Cos[x]] // Simplify;
(* 1/(5 r^4) Cos[x] (-18 - 10 r - 5 r^2 - 10 r^2 u0[r] + 
   10 (-1 + r) r^2 [u0'[r] - 10 r^3 u0''[r] + 5 r^4 u0''[r]) *)

DSolveValue[Last[%] == 0, u0[r], r, GeneratedParameters -> C0] // Simplify
(* 1/20 (138 - 36/r - 20 C0[1] + 20 r C0[1] - 20 C0[2] - Log[262144] + 
   r Log[262144] - 40 Log[-2 + r] + 40 r Log[-2 + r] - 
   2 (-1 + r) Log[2 - r] (-9 + 5 C0[2] - 8 Log[r]) + 90 Log[r] - 
   58 r Log[r] - 10 C0[2] Log[r] + 10 r C0[2] Log[r] + 
   Log[65536] Log[r] - r Log[65536] Log[r] + 8 Log[r]^2 - 
   8 r Log[r]^2 + 16 (-1 + r) PolyLog[2, r/2]) *)
```

The many constants are determined by the PDE boundary conditions, not specified in the question.